# Is there ever a reason not to follow this cascading SQL reindexing refactoring pattern?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

Suppose it is determined a compound index is needed on a table on columns `A,B`.

This index is added.

If there was already a compound index `A,C`, is there any reason not to change it to `C,A`?

And once that is done, if there was already an index on `C,D,E` is there any reason not to change it to `D,C,E`?

In general, when adding an index triggers an opportunity for this type of index 'refactoring', are there any reasons not to move forward with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too generic ABCD columns. The indexing should be in context with optimizing of joins between tables and where querying criteria makes the most sense.  Take a simple example of an order, orderdetail setup.  Of course you would want an index on the order detail table on the orderID of the header.

But now, on the header. You have a customerID, orderID and orderDate.  And you want a query all customers who have ordered on a day... or a single customer and all dates ordered...  The index order can significantly be better in swapped fashion. (date, customer) and (customer, date)
The date/customer on the first scenario would no be as efficient.

Think of the priority of indexed columns as this.  You have a room of boxes.  Each box has represents a single date.  Within the box are ordered by customer.  For the first query, no problem, get the box, you have your customers, you are done.

Now, use that same scenario for the second query.  You open the first dated box and look for the customer... Nope, not there... go to the next dated box, nope... the third, yes, etc...  You should be able to see the importance of the context of data, querying and the indexes that help support them.

Comment: Thanks. So in short, if all of the indexed columns have high specificity on their own, I'm safe to follow the pattern. If one of the indexes has low specificity without the 'prefix index', then I could be in trouble by swapping them. Does that sum it up?

Comment: @z5h, yup.... Also consider looking into "covering indexes" when dealing with small return column datasets so you don't have to go back to the raw data pages... the entire query can be qualified from the index directly.